# UIView not being removed from UIWindow

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4

I have a `UIView()` added to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` so it covers the screen in totality.

To that `UIView` I add as sublayer a gradient color (which I think it's not causing the problem here).

After some initial setup I try to remove this view with `removeFromSuperview()` call but it doesn't get removed.

I'm dispatching on main because I'm making this removal call in a background thread.

Here's the related code:

**Adding the view to keyWindow**

```
fileprivate func addOverlapView() {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    self.overlapView = UIView(frame: frame)

    let overlapGradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    overlapGradient.colors = [self.fromColor.cgColor, self.toColor.cgColor]
    overlapGradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    overlapGradient.frame = self.view.bounds
    overlapGradient.masksToBounds = true
    overlapView.layer.insertSublayer(overlapGradient, at: 0)

    let textLabel = UILabel()
    textLabel.text = "Configuring user settings"
    textLabel.textAlignment = .center
    textLabel.textColor = .white

    overlapView.addSubview(textLabel)

    textLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: overlapView.frame.width, height: 100)
    textLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlapView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    textLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlapView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(overlapView)

}
```

And then I'm trying to remove it with the following call:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.overlapView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

But somehow the view doesn't get removed.

Any hint on what may be causing this?

Comment: After some initial setup I try to remove this view with removeFromSuperview() call but it doesn't get removed.What is that setup?

Comment: It is server related, some background threads but nothing UI related

Comment: I tried with tap gesture , and that is working fine.

Comment: @lvan Cantarino right the self will be required because you got a closure, I got confused . well you need to show more code to solve issue.At what point are you trying to remove view?

Comment: I’m trying to remove the view, through a NSNotification Observer that fires once a Background task / server is completed.

Comment: Everything on that notification observer works as expected beside the view removal